# Get WordPress Shortcode atts value from a page by coding

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I have created a shortcode like, [my-shortcode id="2"] and added it in a page. I want to get the value of attribute "id" by coding, so that I can do something for [my-shortcode] which value is 2.

I'm trying to retrieve attributes value from a different function. The function will check if there is any shortcode on the page, and if so, what is the value of the 'id'? Is that possible?

Comment: Please see the [Wordpress Codex documentation for shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the followinig code within your functions.php

Within your functions.php you can add a new shortcode called "my_shortcode".
You can achieve this by using the **[add_shortcode( string $tag, callable $callback )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)** function.

```
//init shortcode => [my_shortcode id="1"]
add_shortcode('my_shortcode', 'shortcode_render_function');

//function to display your shortcode
function shortcode_render_function($atts, $content) {

    //set shortcode attributes
    $custom_atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => ''    
    ), $atts ); 
   
    //check if attribute is set
    if(!empty($custom_atts[id])){
        $id = $custom_atts[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got this answer in somewhere already. But, this is not I'm looking for. I'm trying to retrieve attributes value from a different function. The function will check if there is any shortcode on the page, and if so, what is the value of the 'id'?

Answer (score 0):

Your registered shortcode function can have two arguments. The first one contains attribute key-value pairs like your `id="2"`. The second one contains content between the opening and closing tag of your shortcode.

If your shortcode function is `my_shortcode_handler`, you can get the attributes like so:

```
function my_shortcode_handler($attr, $content = null) {
  $attr = shortcode_atts([
    'id' => false, // default value
  ], $attr);

  // ... do something with $attr['id']
}
```

`shortcode_atts` sets default values overwriting them with actual arguments. Meaning, it will contain the default if the user did not specify the `id` explicitly and just typed `[my-shortcode]`.

Comment: Actually, I was trying to retrieve attributes value from a different function. The function will check if there is any shortcode on the page, and if so, what is the value of the 'id'? May be this is the only solution you gave. I have to find the value in the shortcode function only.

Comment: @MdIftekharul did you ever find an answer?